# Node.js: Calculation of AWS Signature

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services

I am having issues with getting AWS Signature calculation working. The objective is to read 4 passed as part of URL (key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName)and use them for calculation of the signature. I am not Node.js expert, and you assistance and time are appreciated.

1. Example of URL: http://localhost:3000/getSignature?key=ASIAJSLN6INQGFK7XX7Q&dateStamp=26072015&regionName=us-east-1&serviceName=IAM
2. AWS specification for java script: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html#signature-v4-examples-jscript
3. Example of signature: Signature=265f004b995af67102af3c5ff84b0f34e091165a190ac62730c76e919d91b77a

My Node.js code...

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

//Crypto
var Crypto = require('crypto-js');

// routes
app.get('/getSignature', function(req, res) {
    var key = req.param('key');
    var dateStamp = req.param('dateStamp');
    var regionName = req.param('regionName');
    var serviceName = req.param('serviceName');

    var kDate = Crypto.HMAC(Crypto.SHA256, dateStamp, "AWS4" + key, {asBytes: true});
    var kRegion = Crypto.HMAC(Crypto.SHA256, regionName, kDate, {asBytes: true});
    var kService = Crypto.HMAC(Crypto.SHA256, serviceName, kRegion, {asBytes: true});
    var kSigning = Crypto.HMAC(Crypto.SHA256, "aws4_request", kService, {asBytes: true});
    res.send(key + ' ' + dateStamp + ' ' + regionName + ' ' + serviceName + ' ' + kSigning);

});

// start the server
app.listen(port);
console.log('Server started! At http://localhost:' + port);
```

I am getting the following run-time errors:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function    at
>   c:\Users\xxx\WebstormProjects\Unscriptd\app.js:34:24    at
>   Layer.handle [as handle_request]
>   (c:\Users\xxx\WebstormProjects\Unscriptd\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>   at next
>   (c:\Users\xxx\WebstormProjects\Unscriptd\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)

Crypto-js library was imported.

Comment: Can you show us line 34 of app.js? It does not appear to be here.

Answer (score 0):

Dude. I copied your code to my github (to reproduce). https://github.com/ttwd80/so-nikolai-nodejs.git

Here are the steps that I did

`cd /tmp
rm -rf so-nikolai-nodejs
git clone https://github.com/ttwd80/so-nikolai-nodejs.git
cd so-nikolai-nodejs
wc -l app.js 
npm install crypto-js
npm install express
node app.js`

and it showed me:

`Server started! At http://localhost:3000`

Not so sure why you are getting an error.

maybe you can try to repeat these steps?

The thing is, your error complain about line 34 but your code does not have this line.
It may be possible you are looking at a different file and executing a different file.

Let me know how it goes.

Thanks.